# what type of database should be used to store millions of restaurants and query them

Tags: mysql, database, oracle, bigdata, nosql

I am designing a system which will store all the available restaurants in the world and then user should be able to perform generic search on such large data sets with very low letency. Will normal RDBMS be enough for this or should I go for big data framework like cassandra. What should I use to make generic search efficient. What will be the best way to store comments for each restaurant.

Comment: Many databases and technologies are suitable for the problem you describe.  However, Stack Overflow is not a site for recommending particular software solutions.  Please review guidelines for asking questions.  Here is a place to start:  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: I've see stats that suggest that, worldwide, there are on average something like 2 restaurants for every 1000 people. This is a gross generalisation because countries like Russia have a modest restaurant culture whereas countries like Japan and Korea have a huge restaurant culture. Nevertheless, if we take that figure at face value then it translates to something like 14-15 million restaurants worldwide. Allow a 20% margin of error and you've got 18m restaurants. With appropriate partitioning, and depending upon how you manage historical data, a normal RDBMS can just about cope with that.

Comment: "all the available restaurants in the world"...Given that populating the dataset is going to cost several million dollars, I would recommend setting aside some of that money now to set up a competent development team and pay for proper design work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use any RDBMS to store your data. But for a fast search use a search engine like [lucene](https://lucene.apache.org/core/) which offer variety of fast search and aggregations.

Using lucene directly may involve more effort so you can use already available tools built around lucene like [solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) and [elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/).

Answer (score 0):

So the first question is: how much data do you think will be there?
Big data approaches are more suitable for lets say billions of records, but of course if you don't have the proper hardware and database design, a few million records could cause very poor performance on a MySQL server, for example.

NoSQL is more suitable for non related related data, and I think in your case there will be many relations between the tables (for example you could have restaurants table having direct relation (with foreign key for example) with `restaurant_comments` table.

In this case using MySQL (innoDB engine) will be very useful when for example you delete a restaurant - all its comments can be deleted with it, and save disc space and time.

If you plan to have no more than 100-200 million restaurants with a proper hardware (dedicated MySQL server or multiple servers with a load balancer), and you design your database (tables, relations, data types and indexes) in a good way, then you will have excellent performance.

If you plan on having a lot more data and many users querying that data a lot, then you should probably consider using Apache Hadoop (with HBase or Cassandra).